How does recursive tail optimization work?
How does recursive tail call optimization work in regards to what is placed/removed from the call stack?  Specifically for LISP like languages? Any insight at assembly level will be helpful.
I show the following picture as start. I’m assuming if the calling function has a recursive call as the third argument to IF the local arguments can be removed from the stack as they won’t be needed by the recursive call. Also I’m assuming function like LET create a separate stack.

Ref: https://zhu45.org/posts/2017/Jul/30/understanding-how-function-call-works/

Read Lambda: The Ultimate Goto

When you make a tail recursive call, it simply reassigns the parameter variables with the recursive call arguments, and goes back to the beginning of the function in the current frame. It turns recursion into a loop.

Nothing else happens to the stack frame.

Another quick explanation I read is that from the point of view of the assembly, you can convert a sequence of CALL/RET with nothing else between as simply a JUMP; it's not completely accurate but I think it helps seeing what is the purpose of the optimization

@Barmar that helps. Interesting article Steele published in 1977 and surprised tail call optimization wasn’t included in Java since he wrote the spec for that

Scheme was designed as a simple language for pedagogy. Tail call optimization becomes harder in more complex languages.

Detail: let is not a function; it is a special form. A let form can be written as a lambda expression. Lambda expressions aren't functions, either, but they do evaluate to functions.

@adabsurdum I suspected let provided another separate stack, that allowed the parameters to be modified, but maybe not

let creates variable bindings. Variable bindings may exhibit stack-like behavior, but AFAIK there is no requirement that a stack is used for this, or that let should implement its own stack. But the linked article is talking about the call stack in assembly language. It seems that you are really asking about how tail call optimization is implemented at the assembly level for lisps. That's pretty broad, but I am adding a couple of tags which might attract someone who can answer.

@adabsurdum Yes I’m looking for how tail call optimization works at the assembly level for lisps.

@coredump agreed, is there someplace where the assembly for this is shown perhaps for any lisp language?

@coredump I don't know exactly but SBCL is open source and does manipulate a lot of assembly

A long time ago I wrote programs for the RCA 1802 (I'm not quite that old, but there were rad-hard versions of it which were interesting to us).
The 1802 was primitive.  In particular it didn't have support for subroutine call and return.  Instead, if you wanted to have subroutines, you'd decide which register was the stack pointer and then
to call a routine

stick the next PC address at the address pointed to by the register you'd decided was the stack pointer;
increment that register;
go to the address of the subroutine.

To return you then just

decrement the stack pointer;
load the address one beyond it into the PC.

(I may have the details wrong, it has been a long time.)
Everyone working on the code for the thing had to agree on which register was the SP (and indeed which register was the PC) and where the stack was and so on.
The system we were working on had very, very little memory (at some point people from the US turned up wanting to buy our thing and said that all software had to be in Ada or FORTRAN.  We laughed).  And some clever person had worked out the following trick:
If your subroutine was going to call another routine and then just return you could avoid the whole ritual described above: you could just go to the address of the subroutine you wanted to call.  This saved all of instructions, stack space and time.
We didn't know this, but we'd just reinvented tail call elimination.
Well, of course, you teach a compiler to do this: when it realises that its about to compile a call to a function which is the very last thing that happens in the function it is compiling, it can instead just compile a jump.
In a language like Common Lisp there are caveats around this.  For instance consider compiling something like
(defun foo (x)
  (let ((*v* x))
    (declare (special *v*))
    (bar (1+ x))))

The call to bar may or may not be a tail call, because it may or may not be the last thing that foo does, depending on how special variables are implemented.  Similar things apply, for instance, to
(defun foo (x)
  (handler-case
      (bar x)
    ...))

Quite likely this call to bar is not a tail call because the condition handlers need to be undone on its return.
Finally quite a lot of Lisp compilers have traditionally only dealt with tail call elimination when the call is directly recursive, because the compiler can then know much more about how the function being called expects to work.  Scheme, on the other hand, requires that all tail calls be eliminated.
